# Проблема при написании шаблона

Tags: drupal, php

Пишу темплейт в drupale.
В коде:

```
$d=count($_items);
$e=$d*127;//Значение валидно, проверял
$aa.="<div id=\"items-related-products\" class=\"items\" style=\"width: ".$e."px\">";
```

на выходе получается

```
<div id="items-related-products" class="items" style="width: 0px;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось проще и глупее.
По аналогии с советом [@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope), начал менять название классов и id. Нашёл свой же скрипт с такой фигнёй:

```
  jQuery("#items-related-products").width(totalWidthRelated);
```

Закрыто.

Answer (score 0):

А если так

```
$d=count($_items);
$e=$d*127;//Значение валидно, проверял
$aa.="<div id=\"items-related-products\" class=\"items\" style=\"width: ".strval($e)."px\">";
```

Comment: Да можно да же так:
$aa.="<div id=\"items-related-products\" class=\"items\" style=\"width: 1895px\">";
И так:
$aa.="<div id=\"items-related-products\" class=\"items\">";

Проблема в том что где-то и как-то друпал присваивает своё значение :(

Comment: Для того, чтобы это проверить, дайте переменным другие имена.

Comment: Тоже пробовал. Эти переменные больше нигде не фигурируют.

Answer (score 0):

А Вы уверены, что видите вывод именно этого блока кода? Меня так скажем напрягает точка с запятой после px в выводе. В исходном коде она отсутствует. И если это не опечатка при копировании на этот сайт, то наиболее вероятная причина в том, что Вы анализируете не ту ветку кода.

В таких случаях очень помогает функция error_log:

```
error_log(var_export($e, true));
```

Comment: В том что это нужная ветка кода уверен, так как этот класс больше ни одному тегу не присваивается. Тчкзпт подставляется на каком-то этапе подставлется друпалом. И как раз не могу отследить где и как.
В лог занеслось:
[Thu May 17 11:10:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.3] 1905, referer: http://localsite/  
Честно не могу понять к чему это.